# Symfony 7 MapRequestPayload Valdation with private Constructor

Tags: php, symfony

I've set up a little demo Project with Symfony 7 in order to evaluate the possibilities with MapRequestPayload and run into the issue, that I seem to miss something in order to use named constructors.

My controller:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Controller;

use App\DependencyInjection\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Attribute\MapRequestPayload;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Attribute\Route;

final readonly class HelloWordController
{
    #[Route('/')]
    public function helloWord(#[MapRequestPayload('json')] Request $request): Response
    {
        return new JsonResponse(['email' => $request->email->asString()]);
    }
}
```

My Request DTO:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\DependencyInjection;

use App\DependencyInjection\Email;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

final class Request
{

    #[Assert\Valid] public Email $email;
    public function __construct(
        string $email,
    ){
        $this->email = EmailV6::fromString($email);
    }
}
```

My ValueObject:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\DependencyInjection;
use App\DependencyInjection\IsEmail;

final class Email
{
    private string $email;
    private function __construct(string $email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public function asString(): string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public static function fromString(#[IsEmail] string $email): self
    {
        return new self($email);
    }
}
```

The Constraint:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\DependencyInjection;

use Attribute;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Attribute\HasNamedArguments;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

#[Attribute]
final class IsEmail extends Constraint
{
    #[HasNamedArguments]
    public function __construct(
        array       $groups = null,
        mixed       $payload = null,
        public bool $isNullable = false,
    )
    {
        parent::__construct([], $groups, $payload);
    }
}
```

And the Validator:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\DependencyInjection;

use InvalidArgumentException;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\UnexpectedTypeException;

final class IsEmailValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate(mixed $value, Constraint $constraint): void
    {
        if (!$constraint instanceof IsEmail) {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException($constraint, IsEmail::class);
        }

        if ($value === null && $constraint->isNullable) {
            return;
        }
        
        if (!filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(
                sprintf(
                    '"%s" is not a valid email address',
                    $value
                )
            );
        }
    }
}
```

My issue is, that if I try it this way, that the Constraint for Email is never checked.

If I make the constructor public and put the stuff in there it would work, but doesn't fit with our requirements:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\DependencyInjection;
use App\DependencyInjection\IsEmail;

final readonly class Email
{
    public function __construct(#[IsEmail] public string $email)
    {}
}
```

Could someone tell me please, what I've missed to get this running without a public constructor?

Comment: Normally you would put the constraint directly on the property: `final class Email{ #[IsEmail] public string $email; private function __construct(string $email){ /*...*/ }` Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not impossible, because Symfony on MapRequestPayload use Symfony serializer/normalizer, and try to deserialize payload data to object. For more info, see `\Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer`.

1. By default, serializer try deserialize data recursively.
2. If object has constructor, symfony try to create object via constructor. If object does not have constructor, symfony try to get public properties.

But, in you object `Request`, where `email` presented in constructor and in property too. As result, Symfony don't know what have high priority (required to see code, what symfony do in this case).

Better in this case - create custom normalizer for Email object and register this normalizer in system.

```php
namespace Acme;

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DenormalizerInterface;

class EmailNormalizer implements DenormalizerInterface
{
    public function getSupportedTypes(?string $format): array
    {
        return [
            Email::class => true,
        ];
    }

    public function denormalize(mixed $data, string $type, ?string $format = null, array $context = []): ?Email
    {
        return $data ? Email::fromString($data) : null;
    }

    public function supportsDenormalization(mixed $data, string $type, ?string $format = null): bool
    {
        return \is_a($data, Email::class, true);
    }
}
```

After this, Symfony always call this denormalizer for denormalize `Email` object.

Comment: Allright. That could be a road to go. I'll discuss that approach with the team. Thx!